# Organize singles in Entries tab

Tags: entries, control-panel

Looking to build a largish site with Craft and I need a way to organize the entries for content editors/creators. Adding headers down the side will help for channels/structures, but all singles seem stuck in the predefined singles tab.

[image]

I've tried adding a custom field to each page but it doesn't seem possible to sort by a custom field from within the entries view, which makes this rather useless.

Is there anything built in that I'm missing or perhaps a plugin that can help me to group together related content on this page? You can imagine this becoming hard to navigate with dozens or even hundreds of pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doesn't the [Expanded Singles](https://straightupcraft.com/craft-plugins/expanded-singles) plugin do what you're looking for? Best of luck.

Comment: Awesome, yes this looks like exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of a plugin that tackles this or a way around it, but you might want to consider voting for this [feature request](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues/990), which looks to be asking for the same thing.